# Databricks query with distinct sort and alias produces error

Tags: sql, apache-spark-sql, alias, databricks, azure-databricks

I’m trying to use sql query on azure-databricks with distinct sort and aliases

```
SELECT DISTINCT album.ArtistId AS my_alias 
FROM album ORDER BY album.ArtistId
```

The problem is that if I add alias then I can not use not aliased name in the order by clause. `ORDER BY album.ArtistId` part produces an error. `ORDER BY my_alias` works.
If I remove distinct it also works.

```
Error in SQL statement: AnalysisException: cannot resolve '`album.ArtistId`' given input columns: [my_alias]; line 2 pos 22;
'Sort ['album.ArtistId ASC NULLS FIRST], true
+- Distinct
   +- Project [ArtistId#2506 AS my_alias#2500]
      +- SubqueryAlias spark_catalog.chinook.album
         +- Relation[AlbumId#2504,Title#2505,ArtistId#2506] parquet
```

Seems like after `Project` step original column name is lost.
That behavior is unexpected for SQL compared to SQL dialects. And I can not find any documentation about it.

Is there any way to make this query run as is, without modification maybe by changing some execution flags?

Comment: You could always duplicate the column and don't alias it, shouldn't add on too much query time

Comment: The query is generated in sqlalchemy, I prefer to keep code same for all sql dialects.

Comment: Also aliases are required when a query contains multiple joins between two tables. Table1 join Table2 join Table1, then to get distinct column names aliases are required. And for self joins.

Comment: Actually no, they are not required, only table name aliases are needed, not column names.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up just disabling column aliases, but keeping table name aliases. So queries with self join looks like this:

```
select c2.id from Customer as c1 join Customer as c2 on c1.id = c2.id
```

No aliases and no problems with self joins.

Answer (score 1):

When tried, I also got the same error.

As a workaround

1. You can give the column position value (number) in the **Order By** clause.

   ```
   select distinct teacher_id, name, age, id as student_id 
   from student 
   order by 4
   ```

[image]

2. You can give the column **alias** name in the Order By.

   ```
   select distinct teacher_id, name, age, id as student_id 
   from student 
   order by student_id
   ```

Please feel free to post your question in [Microsoft Q&A](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/ask.html) forum where the product team will monitor them closely.